# "The index is independent of the Dirac operator"

Tags: index-theory, clifford-algebras, dirac-operator

Fix a Clifford module bundle $E$ on a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ and let $D_0$ and $D_1$ be two Dirac operators (compatible with the Clifford action). The proof of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem in [Heat Kernels and Dirac operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) makes use of the fact that in this situation $$\mathrm{ind}(D_0)=\mathrm{ind}(D_1).$$
The proof of the equality is discussed on page 125. However I feel like there is gap in the proof:

We seem so to assume that we can find a family $(D_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ of Dirac operators such that the function
$$[0,1]\ni t\mapsto\mathrm{ind}(D_t)\in\mathbb{R}$$
is continuous. Since the image is contained in $\mathbb{Z}$, it would be constant. In fact there is a very obvious candidate: As explained on page 117 we have that $A=D_1-D_0$ is function-linear, i.e. $A\in \Gamma(M,\mathrm{End}(E))$ and
$$D_t=D_0+tA$$
is a Dirac operator for all $t\in[0,1]$. But how do we know that the above-mentioned function is continuous?

The authors suggest to use the McKean-Singer formula, but it was only proven for a Dirac operator which happens to be symmetric w.r.t. some metric. I assume that this is not the case for all Dirac operators (?), so can we avoid using McKean Singer? Or does the latter actually hold for all Dirac operators?

Comment: You are right, from the proof of Theorem 3.51, we can see that the author implicitly assume that each $D^z$ is self-adjoint with respect to certain metric data (depend on $z$). There is a very general theorem in functional analysis: the index of Fredholm operator is locally constant. I think the authors did not use this result for the sake of self-containment.

Comment: @Local Thank you for the comment, but I don't quite see how this resolves the issue. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for a Dirac operator $D$, it extends to a Fredholm operator
\begin{equation}
D^+\colon H^1(M,E^+)\to L^2(M,E^-),
\end{equation}
see Lawson-Michelsohn "Spin Geometry", Page 193, Theorem 5.2.

Also, a classical result in functional analysis says the index of the Fredholm operator is locally constant, see for instance Lemma 16.18 of https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-965-geometry-of-manifolds-fall-2004/8a7e4dd837d1bdd6988e0330babb8c5e_lecture16_17.pdf

Therefore, using the above lemma for the family $t\in [0,1]\mapsto tD_0^++(1-t)D_1^+$, the index is constant as required.

To see that the Fredholm index
\begin{equation}
Ind(D^+)=\dim \mathrm{kernel}(D^+)-\mathrm{codim\ range}(D^+)
\end{equation}
coincides with the one you want, we only need to prove that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{codim\ range}(D^+)=\dim \ker(D^-).
\end{equation}
Now we consider the dual $D^- $ of $D^+$
\begin{equation}
D^-\colon L^2(M,E^-)\to H^{-1}(M,E^+),
\end{equation}
Using Rudin Functional Analysis Theorem 4.12, we get
\begin{equation}
L^2(M,E^-)=\ker D^-\oplus \overline{\mathrm{range}(D^+)},
\end{equation}
and since $D^+$ is Fredholm, its image is closed, $\overline{\mathrm{range}(D^+)} =\mathrm{range}(D^+)$, so
\begin{equation}
L^2(M,E^-)=\ker D^-\oplus\mathrm{range}(D^+),
\end{equation}
from which we clearly get $\mathrm{codim\ range}(D^+)=\dim \ker(D^-)$ as required.

A subtle point is to distinguish different adjoints, first,
\begin{equation}
(D^+)^*\colon L^2(M,E^-)\to H^{1}(M,E^+),
\end{equation}
is defined by
\begin{equation}
((D^+)^*s,t)_{H^{1}(M,E^+)}=(s,D^+t)_{L^2(M,E^-)}
\end{equation}
for $s\in L^2(M,E^-),t\in H^{1}(M,E^+)$. But remember that this adjoint is NOT the way we define $D^-$, because $D^-$ is defined via the $L^{2}(M,E^+)$ product, not the $H^{1}(M,E^+)$ product:
\begin{equation}
((D^+)^*s,t)_{L^{2}(M,E^+)}=(s,D^+t)_{L^2(M,E^-)},
\end{equation}
that is why $(D^+)^*s$ is in $H^{-1}(M,E^+)$, not $H^{1}(M,E^+)$.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. But I am still not sure that this resolves the issue: The index of$$D=\begin{pmatrix}0&D^1\\D^0&0\end{pmatrix}$$is defined by$$\operatorname{ind}(D)=\dim\ker{D^0}-\dim\ker{D^1}$$ and does not equal the Fredholm index of $D$. I know that proposition 3.48 says that the index of $D$ equals the Fredholm index of $D^0$, but in that proposition it is assumed that $D$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Filippo I modified the notation to solve the confusion of $0$ and $1$ being used to represent odd and even parts or the value of $t$.

Comment: Hmm given two Fredholm operators $A_0$ and $A_1$ I can of course not just use the lemma for the family $t\mapsto A_t=A_0+t(A_1-A_0)$. Are you using that in our case 1) $A_t$ is Fredholm for all $t$ and 2) the function $t\mapsto A_t$ is a continuous function to the topological space of Fredholm operators?

Comment: @Filippo Yes, indeed the set of Fredholm operators is open in the space of bounded linear operators (with respect to the operator norm), and we easily check that $t\mapsto A_t$ is continuous in the topological space of bounded linear operators.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. But there is still the issue that I pointed out in my first comment, namely that it is not clear that the definition of the index in the book and your definition are equivalent in the non-symmetric case.

Comment: @Filippo I uploaded the detail of this.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I looked into Rudin's book and unfortuntaly I can not quite follow: According to theorem 4,12 the kernel of $T$ ($T^*$) equals the annihilator of the range of $T^*$ ($T$). May I ask where the closure in your answer comes from?

Comment: The identity $N(D^-)=(R(D^+))^{\perp}$ is for two subspaces of the Hilbert space $L^2(M,E^-)$. There is a basis result in functional analysis: for subspaces $A$ and $B$ of a Hilbert space $H$, $A$ is the orthogonal complement of $B$ (orthogonal complement corresponds to annihilator here), is equivalent to say that $A\oplus \overline{B}=H$: use the fact that an orthogonal complement of a $B$ is equal to the orthogonal complement of $\overline{B}$ and Corollary 12.14 of https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/Hilbert-Spaces.pdf

Comment: Oh okay, I understand your reasoning now, but I don't see why you can apply theorem 4.12 to obtain $R(D^+)^\perp = N(D^-)$: This would require that$$D^+:H^1\to H^0$$is the adjoint of $$D^-:H^0\to H^{-1}$$but this can not be the case since the adjoint of $A\in B(H_1,H_2)$ is an element of $B(H_2,H_1)$, right?

Comment: I updated it, hope this explains everything, but...such a detailed functional analysis minicourse...without even one vote?

Comment: +1 for the minicourse. Unfortunately I can not accept the answer yet: As I said before, proposition 3.48 in the book already tells us that the index of $D$ equals the Fredholm index of $D^+$ if $D$ is symmetric, or equivalently (assuming that $E^0\perp E^1$) if $D^+$ is the adjoint of $D^-$. I thought that you are trying to show that the two indices are also equal in the non-symmetric, but to me it currently it looks like you are still assuming that $D^+$ is the adjoint of $D^-$.

Comment: That being said, another interpretation may be that the authors simply chose the wrong definition for the index, i.e. the index of $D$ should be defined to be the Fredholm index of $D^+$ to obtain that the index is constant on the set of Dirac operators and for the symmetric case we have that they are equal, so the proof of the index theorem should still work. But of course I am not confident enough to consider this the correct conclusion.

Comment: Yes the Fredholm index of $D^+$ probably is more intrinsic. The authors of this book are world-class experts on index theory...I would hardly say they are wrong, I think they just work under the implicit assumptions of symmetric case, so their definition is consistent with the Fredholm index.

Comment: Btw, I was wrong that you proved the result already established in the book: The $D^+$ on the RHS of the equation$$\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(D^+)-\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(D^-)=\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}(D^+)-\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{coker}(D^+)$$
in proposition 3.48 is a function from $\Gamma(M,E^+)$
 to $\Gamma(M,E^-)$, whereas your $D^+$
 is a function between two Sobolev spaces. But combining your result and proposition 3.48 shows that $\operatorname{ind}(D^+)$ is independent of the interpretation of $D^+$.